pdf figure repeats and overlays other figures
My tex file seems fine when you download it, but on google preview (like in email but will sometimes go away if you zoom in far enough) and sometimes for others viewing the pdf, the figures get overlaid and repeated over each other.
I am not sure if it is the float options for the figures causing this or what else it could be. It is quite strange to me because the figures themselves are pdfs and do not have transparent backgrounds, yet they get overlaid on other figures with a transparent background. The pdf file for the figure is a composite of all three plots on one page, yet in the preview/rendering the first plot gets transposed over the others. In addition, a plot from another page is stamped on top a couple of times. Not sure how to debug or what to do, thankful for any suggestions.
Example code for figures:
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.90\linewidth]{fig/FINALIZED PLOTS/fig_1-cropped.png}
\caption{}
\label{Fig1}
\end{figure}




Welcome! This looks more like a rendering issue than a problem with the PDF itself? Especially if parts of other pages are appearing on this one. If you definitely think it is something about the PDF itself, can you provide code we can use to reproduce the problem? Help preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228. Does this happen only in web browsers' viewers or can you reproduce it in a standard PDF viewer?
